# not showing immediate change in the layout while changing orientation in android device react native

Tags: android, google-maps, reactjs, react-native

When I was trying to load screen in landscape view from potrait in android device then the layout is not rendered properly as shown below:[image]

[image]

Now again when I try to change view from landscape to portrait view , still the same problem repeats as below:
[image]

[image]

But when I reload the view , it is rendered properly.So I want the view to be rendered automatically when screen orientation changes without having to reload ..Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tell the system that you meant to handle screen changes for yourself by specifying android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in the  tag. This way the activity will not be recreated, but will receive a callback instead (which you can ignore as it's not useful for you).

2.You could lock the activity in one orientation by adding android:screenOrientation="portrait" (or "landscape") to  in your manifest.

3.As some of the answers suggested, you could distinguish the cases of your activity being created for the first time and being restored from savedInstanceState. This is done by overriding onSaveInstanceState and checking the parameter of onCreate.

Comment: Ya I have already done this in manifest file.. There may be something else to be resolved for its solution

Comment: okay I will try that once using onSaveInstanceState on android activity ..

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your activity in manifest

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"